# SimPy 3 - Interrupt on terminated job

Tags: simpy

I have an interrupt in my code which sometimes works, and sometimes gives the following error message.

`RuntimeError: <Process(executeJobs) object at 0x7f3542880890> has terminated and cannot be interrupted.`

I have checked that the object still exists, why am I still receiving this error?

I would also be glad to receive any other resources than http://simpy.readthedocs.org/ as I have already been through the documentation many times.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `Process` instance still exists but is no longer [alive](https://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_reference/simpy.events.html#simpy.events.Process.is_alive).  This means that the generator function that it executes (`executeJobs` in your case) is exhaused / has returned.

Comment: Hi Stefan, sorry for chasing you around the internet! Why would a function complete while the Process still exists? Can you also please explain to me what alive means in a little more detail than what is written in the documentation?

Comment: I thinks this might be what you are looking for: https://simpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topical_guides/simpy_basics.html. You should also make sure to understand the guides about  events and process interaction.